# KDE/PLASMA splash screen customization

Tags: kde, kde-plasma-workspace

I would like to change my splash screen image in KDE/PLASMA.

I have made a custom theme, and changed the pic locate in

```
/usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.my_theme.desktop/contents/splash/images/kde.svgz
```

I would like to change the size of the picture though. This should be controlled in the file:

```
/usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.arch_custom.desktop/contents/splash/Splash.qml
```

which reads

```
Rectangle {
    id: topRect
     width:  parent.width
     height: (root.height / 3) - bottomRect.height - 1
    y: root.height
    color: "#4C000000"
    Image {
        source: "images/kde.svgz"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        sourceSize.height: 128
        sourceSize.width: 128
    }
}
```

I have tried to edit different part of this, but the pic is always the same. What should I edit to change the splash image size change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the kde.svgz file with inkscape resized the frame first then modify your image to match the frame. I make the image double what I need because once you resized everything in inkscape you control the actual size that's viewed by editing your main.qml file.

That to control the size just modify:

```
sourceSize.height: 128
sourceSize.width: 128
```

E.g., mine is set like this:

```
Rectangle {
    id: topRect
    width: parent.width
    height: (root.height / 3) - bottomRect.height - 1
    y: root.height
    color: "#4C000000"
    Image {
        source: "images/kde.svgz"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        sourceSize.height: 300
        sourceSize.width: 300
    }
}
```

After doing that save and test your splash. If you followed correctly you should end up with something like:

[ModdedSplash](http://s7.postimg.org/ohnhmi8t7/splash.png)

Comment: I tried this and didn't work, but maybe the change was too little to be perceived.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work..Where is the main.qml file you talk about? I was editing the Splash.qml file (which contains the same lines you posted)

Comment: I think the issue is that all my files are copied from the breeze theme, hence all .qml still look at folders inside the breeze installation. Do you know which files hold the path that all qml files are using?

Comment: Got it, it works if I edit the files of the Breeze theme. There is still some issue with my custom themes that I have to sort out.

Comment: In your theme you should have an .rc file. You need to edit this as well. The theme name should match your folders name. For example my main folder for the theme is called DeadlyArch. In the .rc file I would rename everything from breeze to DeadlyArch.The reason your theme still looks at the breeze folder is because this rc file is still default.

Comment: I cannot find any .rc file in any of the plasma folders in /usr/share/plasma. Is there any directory I should look for? Or is this for an older version?

Comment: This is for plasma, might be because I use arch linux. I zipped the theme you can download and modify it if you like. It should work on your system as well because I tested it in Kali and Ubuntu as well. [link]http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=14335471826698141909